# How to debug hidden powershell scripts?

Tags: debugging, powershell

I'm writing a script that normally will get called by another application (VMware vCenter Server). From that application I trigger a batch file (redirect.bat) and pass a variable which is the powershell script name (TestMe.ps1).

The script is placed on a Windows Server and when I go into the command prompt of the Windows Server and call the redirect script, I see that my PowerShell script runs as expected. However when I trigger it from the app the Powershell script is not run or doesn't produce output. I have confirmation that the redirect.bat is run, because the redirect.bat writes a line in a log file.

The vCenter Server app is running under Local System account. Could it be a permissions error? Is LocalSystem allowed to run Powershell scripts?

I now have no clue if the Powershell script even starts, because it (of course) is not visible in my console when running. The batch file always returns errorlevel = 0.

Any tips on how to insert debugging info in the script that should always give output? Tips on how to troubleshoot this?

redirect.bat:

```
set POWERSHELL=C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -noninteractive
SET ERRORLEVEL =
echo %1 > G:\DataStoreAlarms\Log\Redirect-batch.txt
start %POWERSHELL% -command "&"%1"" 
echo Error level:  %ERRORLEVEL% >> G:\DataStoreAlarms\Log\Redirect-batch.txt
```

I call redirect.bat from the command line and from the app like this:

```
redirect.bat G:\DataStoreAlarms\Scripts\TestGabrie.ps1
```

TestGabrie.ps1:

```
$String = "This is a test"
$String | Out-File -FilePath "G:\DataStoreAlarms\Log\Powershell.txt" -Append
```

Regards
Gabrie

Comment: What OS is the VCenter server running?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 (NT 6.2). But as said, it all works when I run it from the command line on the server.

Comment: On that OS, the Local System account doesn't have access to network resources.  Try the Network Service account.

Comment: I can't switch the account vCenter Server is running on. That would be a major impact. vCenter Server is managing our datacenter with over a 1000 VMs :-)

Is there a different solution possible? Can I switch accounts in the batch file?

Comment: You'd have to include credentials in the .bat file in clear text to make that work (bad mojo).  Can you set up a scheduled task running under the Network Service account? The Local System account should be able to run the task on demand.

Comment: you might need to add `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to the batch command to ensure that powershell ignores the execution policy (remoteSigned) by default and runs any script you throw at it. Also, why are you using a START command? You can run powershell.exe directly from the redirect.bat file and redirect stdout to a log file, remembering to redirect stderr and stdin using the &2>1 operator.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seemed to be the START command:

```
start %POWERSHELL% -command "&"%1""
```

After changing it to this, it worked:

```
%POWERSHELL% -command "&"%1""
```

Thanks for all your help.